# Firebase rules. validate only certain fields

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I want to access my firebase "write" only for the next structure:
[image: My structure]

The idea is to forbid data writing by any way like this:

User ->
email
phone
username

Comment: Have you tried anything? What are your current rules?

Comment: @AndréKool I read documentation and tried some examples but no success, currently just read/write auth != null

Comment: @AndréKool i m not familiar with javascript and have difficulty with rules

Comment: So you want users to be able to write ONLY email, phone and username? Do they have to be all present or should they be able to write only 1 or 2 of those fields?

Comment: Better to get all 3 fields from them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want users to be able to have only email, phone and username fields you can use rules simular to this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
        "$user_id": {
            //Every authenticated user can read
            ".read": "auth != null ",
            // grants write access to the owner of this user account
            // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
            ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
            //This line says the new data must have ATLEAST these children
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['email','phone', 'username'])",   
            //You can add individual validation for email, phone and username here     
            "email": { ".validate": true },
            "phone": { ".validate": true },
            "username": { ".validate": true },
            //This rule prevents validation of data with more child than defined in the 2 lines above (or more if you specify more children)
            "$other": { ".validate": false }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

For more information about validating your data you can take a look at [the firebase security docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data).

Comment: Thank you very much, gonna to test it now!